# C++ merging two linked lists segmentation fault and core dump error

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, coredump

This is my code for merging two linked lists together. When I run it I get a segmentation fault and core dump error. I don't know how to fix it. My brain is fried please help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

class list
{
    struct node *start;
public:
    void create();
    void show();
    void merge(list,list);
};

void list::create()
{
  struct node *nxt_node, *pre_node;
  int value, no, i;
  start=nxt_node=pre_node=NULL;
  cout<<"\nHow many nodes:";
  cin>>no;
  cout<<"Enter "<<no<<" Eelements:";
  for(i=1;i<=no;i++)
  {
    cin>>value;
    nxt_node=new node;
    nxt_node->data=value;
    nxt_node->next=NULL;

    if (start==NULL)
    start=nxt_node;
    else
    pre_node->next=nxt_node;
    pre_node=nxt_node;
  }

}

void list::show()
{
  struct node *ptr=start;


  while(ptr!=NULL)
  {
    cout<<ptr->data<<"->'";
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
}

void list::merge(list l1,list l2)
{
  struct node *nxt_node, *pre_node, *pptr, *qptr;
  int dat;

  pptr=l1.start;
  qptr=l2.start;
  start=nxt_node=pre_node=NULL;
  while(pptr!=NULL && qptr!=NULL)
  {
   if(pptr->data<=qptr->data)
   {
        dat=pptr->data;
        pptr=pptr->next;
    }
    else
        {
    dat=qptr->data;
    qptr=qptr->next;
        }

    nxt_node=new node;
    nxt_node->data=dat;
    nxt_node->next=NULL;

    if(start==NULL)
    {   
     start=nxt_node;
    }   
    else
    {
     pre_node->next=nxt_node;
      pre_node=nxt_node;
    }
  }
  if(pptr==NULL)
  {
    while(qptr!=NULL)
    {
    nxt_node=new node;
    nxt_node->data=qptr->data;
    nxt_node->next=NULL;

    if(start==NULL)
       start=nxt_node;
    else
       pre_node->next=nxt_node;
       pre_node=nxt_node;
       qptr=qptr->next; 
    }
  }
  else if (qptr==NULL)
  {
    while(pptr!=NULL)
    {
        nxt_node=new node;
        nxt_node->data=pptr->data;
        nxt_node->next=NULL;
        if(start==NULL)
           start=nxt_node;
        else
           pre_node->next=nxt_node;
           pre_node=nxt_node;
           pptr=pptr->next;
    }
  }


}

int main()
{
    list l1,l2,l3;
    cout<<"Enter the first list in ascending order.";
    l1.create();
    cout<<"Enter the Second list in ascending order.";
    l2.create();
    cout<<"The first list is:"<<endl;
    l1.show();
    cout<<"The second list is"<<endl;
    l2.show();
    l3.merge(l1,l2);
    l3.show();


return (0);
}
```

Comment: 1) Start `gdb` loading your executable 2) Run and crash 3) Read stack trace 4) Have epiphany and fix

Comment: ... or just use Valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `merge`

```
if(start==NULL)
{   
     start=nxt_node;
}
```

should be changed to

```
if(start==NULL)
{   
     start=nxt_node;
     pre_node=start;
}
```

I think you can figure why.